# Problem searching for exact match from list item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
$('.lists-li').hide();
$('#search').click(function() {
  $('.lists-li').hide();
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  $('.lists-li').each(function() {

    //show match
    if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      //do something   
    } else {
      //do something
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />

<div>
  <ul class="lists-li">
    <li class="lists-list"><a class="lists-li-a" href="/">David</a></li>
    <li class="lists-list"><a class="lists-li-a" href="/">James</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If I use the search box to type in 'James' I get a true match, if I type 'James2323' I get a false match which is how it should be.

The problem I am having is that if I type in 'Jam' I also get a true match but I want it to be an exact match so this should return false. Only exact matches such as 'James' or 'David' should return true.

Does anybody know how I can get the exact match only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly,** you should correct your class name between `.lists-list` and `.lists-li`

```
<ul class="lists-list">
 <li class="lists-li">
       ............
```

**Secondly**, you can compare to get exactly matching value like this

```
var isMached = Value == searchCriteria || searchCriteria == ""; // Assuming that empty criteria will get all items
```

**Finally**, you can use `.toggle()` to trigger show/hide item.

```
$(this).toggle(isMached);
```

```js
$('#search').click(function(){
  var searchCriteria = $('#search-criteria').val().toUpperCase();;
  var isFound = false; // One more problem: Display "Success or Failure"
  $('.lists-li').each(function(){
     var tagA = $(this).find('.lists-li-a')[0];
     var Value = $(tagA).text().toUpperCase();;
     var isMached = Value == searchCriteria || searchCriteria == "";
     $(this).toggle(isMached);
     
     
     if(isMached) isFound = true; // One more problem: Display "Success or Failure"
  });
  
  $("#found-result").html(isFound ? $("#templateMessage").html() : ""); // One more problem: Display "Success or Failure"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>

<div id="found-result"></div>
<div id="templateMessage" style='display:none'><i>Your are here</i></div>

<div>
<ul class="lists-list">
 <li class="lists-li"><a class="lists-li-a" href="/">David</a></li>
 <li class="lists-li"><a class="lists-li-a" href="/">James</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that really helps, if I wanted to trigger a div which contains text such 'success' if a match is found or a div which contains text such as 'failure' if no match has been found, how would I do that?

Comment: I will give you an upvote no problem & if you could help me with adding success and failure messages like the comment above I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, pls take a look at ^^! @LBarc

Comment: Thank you for all your help, you're amazing! I have accepted the answer and upvoted you.

Comment: Glad to help you, Cheers ^^!

Comment: One more question: If I wanted to display a DIV instead of 'success', how would I go about that?